# Get selfrunning content from Tinymce 4.x

Tags: css, class, tinymce, extract

I would like to extract the HTML content created inside a tinyMCE editor to display it without any tinyMCE editor (displaying directly on a page).
 
I'm aware of tinyMCE's `getcontent()` function. But is there another function/parameter/plugin that I oversee with which you can extract it as selfrunning HTML code? There are many tinyMCE classes inside the content and it would be hard work to gather them or to convert them back into CSS styles. 
So either an extraction with the tinyMCE specific classes would be great or any (automated) conversion from classes to CSS styles would be great. Or ist there any other way I oversee?

Comment: TinyMCE has a `preview` plugin that shows the content outside the editor.  Have you looked at how that works?

Comment: Thank you and good point! I just did some checks of preview ouptput (HTML) and beside of the preview container class I couldn't find any other classes. That looks great. That it would be... So I have to find a way how to get/generate the HMTL text out of the preview. Probably another tinyMCE hassle.

Comment: I guess the solution also lies in the code plugin: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/code/ but once again: how to start it programmatically to get generated HTML code.

Comment: There is a format option that can be used to get pure HTML: tinymce.get('texteditor').getContent( {format : 'html'}

Answer (score 0):

There is a format option that can be used to get pure HTML out of tinyMCE content:

```html
tinymce.get('yourEditorId').getContent( {format : 'html'} );
```